# I have created a library but can not create instance of any class from the library. What might be the problem and what should I do to solve it?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

Recently I have worked on a spring boot application and after completing my boss asked me to make this project a library since we are going to use it on some other applications. Hence I make the jar of the project using gradle bootjar command and did all necessary steps defined [here](https://central.sonatype.org/pages/gradle.html) for uploading it to maven central (You guys can check:- artifact: heaven-communication; groupid: com.github.aasthalife). Now here comes the problem. When I add the dependency of that library I just created in my other demo application build.gradle file everything seems ok but when I want to create any instance of any class of the library, it shows in suggestion (my IDE is intellij-community edition) but after selecting, it is underlined in red. It says to import class but I already did. What is the problem here? I appreciate your time. Thanks

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) --- Does the program compile? I.e. is is "just" an IDE issue?

Comment: No it does not compile. It says this class does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I have found the mistake that I have done making the jar file of the library. I did not add: "jar{enabled=true}" command in my build.gradle file. I thought gradle jar command takes care of everything, but no. So, that is why it did not create any proper jar. After adding the command and running gradle jar command I solved this issue. Thank you all for your time.